# How to cancel All subscriptions on a plan in Stripe?

Tags: java, stripe-payments, payment, subscription, billing

I read on Stripe docs :

> Deleting a plan does not affect any existing subscribers of that plan,
>   but new customers cannot be subscribed to it

I want to delete a plan and Cancel all subscriptions on it on Stripe. Is there anyway do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the List Subscriptions [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list) and pass the `plan` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list#list_subscriptions-plan) to find all subscriptions on that plan. For each one, you can then call the Cancel Subscription [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list).

There is no call or automated way to cancel all those subscriptions and you need to write a script to cancel them sequentially in the API.

Comment: If i want to cancel the subscriptions on a plan at the end of the current cycle, i should update the subscription object cancel_at_period_end to true instead of Cancel Subscription API, right?